# how to set default value to JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Please help me to do this!

I'm getting data array from database by month. The problem I'm having is that I'm fetching data like ***this***

```
[{January: 6}, {February: 2}, {October: 7}, {December: 4}, {November: 5374}]
```

wherever there is null I don't even get any value which causes problem for me to work so I want data like ***this***

```
[{January: 6}, {February: 2}, {March: 0}, {April: 0}, {May: 0}, {June: 0}, {July: 0}, {August: 0}, {September: 0}, {October: 7}, {November: 5373}, {December: 4}]
```

but data is fetched dynamically from database which is giving me only values which are more than 0. I just want to get all months with default values as 0.

Comment: This is not enough info to help you. What database? How do yo call it (what query)? Also, are all months actually present in the database with the value `null` (or `0`)? Or absent altogether? With the current information, it's impossible to say for certain why nullish entries get skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build an object and take an array of minth names for creating an array of objects.

```js
const
    year = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    data = [{ January: 6 }, { February: 2 }, { October: 7 }, { December: 4 }, { November: 5374 }],
    object = Object.assign({}, ...data),
    result = year.map(month => ({ [month]: object[month] || 0 }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all months using `Date.toLocaleString()` and `array#from` and then assign `0` to missing month.

```js
const input = [{January: 6}, {February: 2}, {October: 7}, {December: 4}, {November: 5374}],
      allMonths = Array.from({length: 12}, 
              (_,i) => new Date(2020,i).toLocaleString({}, {month: 'long'})),
      lookup = Object.assign(...input),
      result = allMonths.map(month => ({ [month]: lookup[month] || 0 }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a default list in your program, and if you don't get the data from the database you then refere back to the default list.

```js
let defaults = [{January: 0}, {February: 0}, {March: 0}, {April: 0}, {May: 0}, {June: 0}, {July: 0}, {August: 0}, {September: 0}, {October: 0}, {November: 0}, {December: 0}];

let databaseValue = [{January: 6}, {February: 2}, {October: 7}, {December: 4}, {November: 5374}];

let monthToSearch = "June";
let databaseFound = databaseValue.find(o => o.hasOwnProperty(monthToSearch));
if (!databaseFound){
  databaseFound = defaults.find(o => o.hasOwnProperty(monthToSearch));
}

console.log(databaseFound);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!
You can simply transform the fetched data and update that object by iterating over it.

```js
var data = [{January: 6}, {February: 2}, {October: 7}, {December: 4}, {November: 5374}];

var theMonths = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
  "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

var monthsfetched = data.map(x =>  Object.keys(x)[0]);

theMonths.map(mon => {
  if(!monthsfetched.includes(mon)){  
    let missing_entry = {};
    missing_entry[mon] = 0;
    data.push(missing_entry);
  }
})

console.log(data)
```